# I don't want repeat the same words in swift 3, how do I do?

Tags: arrays, swift, repeat

I'm trying to make an app that will display the words and sentences, but it is often the same word or sentence. How do I do to not repeat the same words.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

var array =  ["word 1",
              "Word 2",
              "Word 3",
              "Word 4",
              "Word 5",
              "Word 6",
              ]

@IBAction func randomWord(_ sender: Any) {
     changeWord()
}



func changeWord() {
    let randomWordGen = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
    label.text = array[randomWordGen]
}
```

Comment: Remove the generated word from `array` so that it isn't available the next time you pick a word.  Repeat until `array` is empty.

Comment: then how do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your func to this:

```
 func changeWord() {
     guard !array.isEmpty else {
          // list is empty
          return 
     }
     let randomInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))
     label.text = array.remove(at: randomInt)
 }
```

the `.remove(at:)` method removes the element from your array at specified Int and returns it.

EDIT: as LeoDabus pointed out. It is indeed slower to compare array's count to zero than using `isEmpty` and accessing the count afterwards. Updated the func.

Comment: thanks! it worked perfectly! it is possible to display a text "No more words" and then start over?